# Get file inode during the file change owner in HDFS Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

how to get file INode in active file?  for example:

under client type command as below:

```
./hadoop fs -chown -R hadoop:hadoop hdfs://nn:9000/A1.txt
```

how to get "A1.txt" file INode during the file change owner operation?

Thanks!

---

Thanks Harsh J for the below answer. I know the API. let me change a way to say: How do I get the pointer to the active file inode if I want to add something to the file inode? Thanks a lot.

---

Thanks Harsh J for the answer. I know the API. 
let me change a way to say:

How do I get the pointer to the active file inode if I want to add something to the file inode? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks Harsh J for the answer. I know the API. let me change a way to say:

How do I get the pointer to the active file inode if I want to add something to the file inode? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Given the unclear question, I am going to assume you seek the details of a given file, complete with all its metadata (such as mtime, atime, owner, etc.), in HDFS.

HDFS APIs provide clients a representation of the internal `INode` in form of a [FileStatus](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html) object. This is also the object retrieved and used by almost all the `hadoop fs` sub-commands.

Using appropriate Java APIs for your HDFS instance, you can retrieve a [FileStatus](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html) object for your path of `hdfs://nn:9000/A1.txt`. An example snippet would look like the below:

```java
Path path = new Path("hdfs://nn:9000/A1.txt");
FileStatus inode = path.getFileSystem(new Configuration())
                       .getFileStatus(path);
// Use inode's information as desired.
// An example to print owner:
System.out.println(inode.getOwner());
```